# Want to make a card in Reactjs but unable to style border color of cards

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I want to make cards in Reactjs. When I style them the border-color isn't working. Actually I want to create a card like this-
[Expecting to make these type of cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXofb.png)

I am new to frontend & react.So I need help.

overall page cards image ->

[my page cards section and cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZLKP.png)

## *Here is my codes-*

**The parent Component card container section->**

```
<div className='Cardsection'>
        <button className="left-btn" onClick={leftbtn}><h1>&lt;</h1></button>
        <button className="right-btn" onClick={rightbtn}><h1>&gt;</h1></button>
        
        <div className="cards-container">
            <Mycard name="Project" Projectimg={Project}/>
            <Mycard name="Project" Projectimg={Project}/>
            <Mycard name="Project" Projectimg={Project}/>
            <Mycard name="Project" Projectimg={Project}/>
            <Mycard cardno='5'/>
            <Mycard cardno='6'/>
            <Mycard cardno='7'/>
            <Mycard cardno='8'/>
            <Mycard cardno='9'/>
            <Mycard cardno='10'/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**cards cotainer css->**

```
.Cardsection{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50vh;
    margin-top: 40rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cards-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

.left-btn, .right-btn{
    width: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.left-btn{
    right: 0;
}

.right-btn{
    left: 0;
}

.left-btn>h1, .right-btn>h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.436);
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**child component code->**

```
<div className='cards-shown'>
      <img src={props.Projectimg} alt="#" />
      <p>{props.name}</p>
    </div>
```

**cards styling->**

```
.cards-shown{
    min-width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    background-color: black;
    border-color:red;
    border-width: 10px;
    gap: 20px;
}

.cards-shown>:nth-child(1){
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: scale(1);
    width: 70%;
}

.cards-shown>:nth-child(2){
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans';
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}
```

I tried to style border color but It's not working. I am expecting to create cards and these cards background will be transparent and only border color will be visible so that it will looks like cards and all the contents that i want to write or add image pass as props.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the [`border-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style?retiredLocale=pl) property

e.g. `border-style: solid;`

```css
.cards-shown {
  min-width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='cards-shown'>
  <img src={props.Projectimg} alt="#" />
  <p>{props.name}</p>
</div>
```